# How to escaping single quote in prepared statement.?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

```
  select group_id,group_name,directory_id from csr_dim_group where group_name IN ('RG-Actuary SecShared Best's Week') and directory_id=?

    PreparedStatement statement = getStatement(sql);
    statement.setLong(1, dirId);
    rs = statement.executeQuery();
```

Getting `SQLServerException`. Can you please help me how to escape single quote in preparedStatement.?

> 2021-11-10 21:32:02,892 ERROR
> [com.mcafee.mesa.reportdbin.util.UpdateDirectoryDbUtil] SQL Exception
> during get directory groups:
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The index 1 is out of
> range.
> at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:234)
> at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.setterGetParam(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:1115)
> at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.setValue(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:1129)
> at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.setLong(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:1429)
> at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.setLong(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:123)
> at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.setLong(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:123)
> at com.mcafee.mesa.reportdbin.util.UpdateDirectoryDbUtil.getDirectoryGroups(UpdateDirectoryDbUtil.java:197)
> at com.mcafee.mesa.server.project.services.directory.UpdateDirectoryHelper.updateDirectoryGroup(UpdateDirectoryHelper.java:584)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show how you put a value inside `sql` and `dirId`.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your use of `PreparedStatement`. When you have a single quote in a SQL string literal, it must be escaped, no matter how you execute the statement.

Answer (score -2):

You would use `\'` in the string to escape the `'`. The `\` is used to escape reserved characters. You can also do `\"` to escape quotes.

Comment: Oh I see. I don't know about that lol